# Trying to find then open a file in a VB form

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, file-search

I am working on a desktop interface, I want to make a button where when I click it it will open a program (.exe). I understand I can use

```
process.start("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2017\acad.exe")
```

However I want to be able to load this program on multiple computers and the file paths will most likely not be the same. Is there a way I can just search C and D drives for acad.exe? or is there a way I can use if statements if C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2017\acad.exe is not found it can try on the D drive? If this is too advanced for VB that is understandable.

Comment: Did you do any research?  The very first hit on google is "How to: Find Files with a Specific Pattern in Visual Basic | Microsoft Docs"

Comment: How do I then open that file that is found?

Comment: Either create a config file to store the path location or make the path location fixed on each machine.